# Force shiny project to a URL

Tags: r, shiny

We have successfully setup the shiny server and we are able to view a project from our website. We are trying to make projects use a specific URL but every job that we run uses a different port. We have the shiny server configured to use port 80 but for whatever reason, the R job ignores the server config and starts on a random port. Is there a way to make shiny use a specific URL instead of just random ports? Is this a function of the pro version? Do i have to setup nginx with a reverse proxy? Is there code for shiny that we can specify a URL? Please advise.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need port 80 for any specific reason or port 1234 will do the job as well?
Do you need to run Shiny server or RScript will be just fine for you?
if any port (instead of URL) + Shiny run from e.g. Jenkins then you can do it easily

Comment: "We are trying to make projects use a specific URL" - can you outline how do you do it at the moment?

Comment: @AlexSkorokhod Currently when a user runs a R script, the result will attempt to listen to some random port but we are only allowing port 80 traffic because it's firewalled. A basic example of what is happening is the job runs, and binds to 127.0.0.1:1452 (ignoring the server shiny-server.conf). What we want is the project to bind to a URL like: 127.0.0.1:80/MyProject

Comment: I could use nginx as a reverse proxy such that when someone goes to the URL mysite.com/MyProject it would be proxied back to 127.0.0.1:1452 but that's not something easily automated. I would prefer that I dont have to "touch" the server every time someone uses the shiny server.

Comment: I have rather bad experience with port 80. Linux will have huge problems updating later on. If you need I can provide you with the example of stable port running through RScript. I'd advise asking your SysAdmin later to map /Myproject outside URL to :1234 inside port

Answer (score 2):

There is a bit confusion in what you define:

> R job ignores the server config

From my experience of running shiny apps on the server, you have 2 basic options:

1. run various flavours of `runApp()` through `Rscript` or setup the and define the port there
2. run the shiny server with all benefits of `shiny-server.conf`

The reason why you would ever use `Rscript` with `runApp()` is that you can run shiny apps without installing shiny server. E.g. you would prefer it on Jenkins server run under Apache. Cheap and fast. Disadvantage - use of port instead of URL.

> every job that we run uses a different port

It looks like to run `runApp()` as it assigns random port unless you forcefully specify one.

Based on your requirements you need to use option 2 "shiny server". 
In this case the port is FIXED at 3838 unless you alter the shiny config file.

If you run shiny server you have full control over nginx and lots of nice features in `shiny-server.conf`.

Following documentation what you need is:

#### Step 1. find and replace the default 3838 port in a config file

Described here: [2.1 Default Configuration](http://docs.rstudio.com/shiny-server/#default-configuration):

```
server {
  Instruct this server to listen on port 3838
  listen 3838;
```

into [2.2.1. Server Hierarchy](http://docs.rstudio.com/shiny-server/#server) listening to 80 instruction

```
server {
  # Instruct this server to listen on port 3838
  listen 80;
```

#### Step 2. Option 1: Link the locations of the apps on your HDD with the URL paths

Details here: [2.7.2 Single app](http://docs.rstudio.com/shiny-server/#host-a-single-application)

Main difference: link of the HDD path to URL is done one by one:

```
server {
  ...
  # Define the location '/MyProject'
  location /MyProject { # path on HDD
    # Run this location in 'app_dir' mode, which will host a single Shiny
    # Application available at '/srv/shiny-server/MyProject'
    app_dir /srv/shiny-server/MyProject
  }
```

#### Step 2. Option 2. Link the locations of the apps folder on your HDD with the URL path suffix

Details here: [2.7.1 Host a Directory of Applications](http://docs.rstudio.com/shiny-server/#host-a-directory-of-applications)

Main difference: You define URL once and ANY new app in the folder will be accessible through URL automatically

```
server {
  ...
  # Define the location '/otherApps'
  location /otherApps {
    # Run this location in 'site_dir' mode, which hosts the entire directory
    # tree at '/srv/shiny-server/apps'
    site_dir /srv/shiny-server/apps;
  }
...
}
```

#### Extra sources of information

Please also check the article on R-Bloggers. It had [very detailed instructions on how to run the shiny server](https://www.r-bloggers.com/shiny-server-on-aws/).